# Phonegap status bar overlaps after inapppbrowser or camera closed

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, statusbar, inappbrowser

I am using the cordova status bar plugin, it works great until I open an inappbrowser or open a camera, after that it overlaps the app.

I have tried following methods:-

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />

 Add 20px margin, but that only works when the above scenario is encountered, else it shows blank 20px space (Used with cordova plugin)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try doing the following to restore the hidden overlap:

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

Comment: @StefanRein and wait for the new iOS 13 issues on Cordova...https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/661

Answer (score 2):

i have solved this using this code after camera is closed.

```
    $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
    $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

Btw, i'm using ngCordova.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

This was fixed in the [StatusBar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/157)

Currently the `NPM registry has only the version 2.4.3` of the `cordova-plugin-statusbar`. The fixed landed in the `Master branch`

So basically for ionic people this would mean you need to add it like this (maybe remove it before):

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#master
```

This installs the master branch from github as plugin for you.

Then run something like this to get it into your Xcode project:

```
ionic cordova build ios --no-build --prod
```

---

**Original Post**

While calling in JavaScript the method `overlaysWebView` with `true` and `false` works, I assume the proper way would be to call the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method natively when the view disappears.

`CDVCamera.m`
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m#L751

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

Right now only `viewWillAppear` is implemented.

---

BTW: Maybe someone knows why the hiding transition of the statur bar works with following code (in the `viewWillAppear` method):

```
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate");
if ([self respondsToSelector:sel]) {
    [self performSelector:sel withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

but not with the following:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And in the `viewWillDisappear` it works only if the afterDelay is left out with the performSelector or the `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` is called.